# Getting a custom post type image using 'get_post_custom'

Tags: custom-post-types, get-posts

I am trying to echo the image src of an image I have uploaded for my custom post type outside of the while loop.

I have used the following:

```
$custom_fields = get_post_custom($_GET['id']);
```

I can easily now use this code to get, for example the phone number:

```
echo $custom_fields['telephone'][0]; // e.g. returns 0800 555 222
```

However, when I try to get an image using the same code, all I get back is a number.

```
echo $custom_fields['logo'][0]; // e.g. returns 247
```

Doing a var_dump of $custom_fields, it seems as though I cannot load this data outside the loop using this function. Does anybody know what I'm supposed to do here without having to do a loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you can get away with

```
$image_upload = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'logo', true); // CALL IMAGE
```

and then display it with

```
echo wp_get_attachment_image($image_upload);  // Echo image
```

Comment: That has in fact worked a treat, thank you very much!

Comment: No worries.  I was just stabbing in the dark, haha.  Don't forget to mark answered ;)

Comment: I see now that the number returned is by get_post_meta and get_post_custom is an attachment ID, which just gets loaded into wp_get_attachment_image.